# why cant i do podman unshare on this directory

Tags: podman

i'm trying to allow my rootless container to ultimately share a volume with a rootful container:

my volume:

```
podman volume create --driver local \
--opt type=volume \
--opt device=/home/_secrets/certbot/_certs \
certs
```

how i created my container with a user that has sudo privileges (note the container has root user):

```
podman run -d \
--name nginx.main -p 0.0.0.0:8081:8080 \
-v /home/avnav/app/_volumes/nginx_main:/etc/nginx \
-v /home/avnav/app/app_p1/homepage/templates/frontpage:/usr/share/nginx/html \
--security-opt label=disable \
-u root \
-v certs:/etc/nginx/_cert \
nginx
```

**Error: error mounting volume cert for container**

ok...but without the this extra -v certs mounting, the server works and serves my webapp.

so, i try to change ownership:

**podman unshare ls -al $(pwd)**

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 nobody nogroup 4096 Aug 19 14:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 nobody nogroup 4096 Aug 19 04:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 nobody nogroup 4096 Aug 19 04:23 _certs
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 4096 Aug 19 14:35 _tokens
```

inside _certs:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 nobody nogroup 4096 Aug 19 04:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 nobody nogroup 4096 Aug 19 14:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 nobody nogroup 4096 Aug 19 04:58 etc
drwxr-xr-x 4 nobody nogroup 4096 Aug 19 04:23 var
```

a bit weird since it does have ownership, but whatever...

**podman unshare chown 1000:1000 -R $(pwd)**

gives me a bunch of these:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/home/_secrets/certbot/_certs': Operation not permitted
```

maybe with sudo??

**sudo podman unshare chown 1000:1000 -R $(pwd)**

```
Error: please use unshare with rootless
```

so what now?

Comment: and even tho SElinux isnt even running i tried it with -v certs:/etc/nginx/_cert:z

Comment: works when i use: -v /home/_secrets/certbot/_certs:/etc/nginx/_cert \  but i want to use the shared volume...

Answer (score 1):

After normally using podman unshare chown 27:27 -R /tmp/database2; all in a sudden I got same message error "Error: please use unshare with rootless" so I had to chown with the mapped user directly but would be nice to find the root problem (this is my workaround; chown 165562:165562 -R /tmp/database2; the uid and gid might be different in your case of course)

Let me know if any of you come to a better solution.